# Blender 2.90.1 export gltf on Ubuntu 20.10 crashes

Tags: export, gltf, linux

I get the following error message when I run Blender 2.9 from the Terminal

```
Read prefs: /home/u/.config/blender/2.90/config/userpref.blend
/run/user/1000/snap.blender/gvfs/ non-existent directory
found bundled python: /snap/blender/47/2.90/python
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I also tried from Blender 2.83.8 and I get same crash.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.  Removing settings helps me.

```
rm ~/.config/blender/2.90
```

At first, you can rename it or move it to another folder and test running Blender.